# I am receiving an SqlException converting numeric data to numeric //ASP.NET Project in Visual Studio (SECOND UPLOAD)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to save data from a form page I have created using a method for a button OnClick. The code is below.

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO[Loans]([CustName], [LoanAmount], [AnualIntRate], [NumPayments]) VALUES(@CustName, @LoanAmount, @AnualIntRate, @NumPayments)";
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=CheapLoans;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO[Loans]([CustName], [LoanAmount], [AnualIntRate], [NumPayments]) VALUES(@CustName, @LoanAmount, @AnualIntRate, @NumPayments)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = custNameTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LoanAmount", SqlDbType.Decimal, 0).Value = decimal.Parse(loanAmtTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AnualIntRate", SqlDbType.Decimal, 0).Value = decimal.Parse(annualInterestRateTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumPayments", SqlDbType.Int, 0).Value = Int32.Parse(numPaymentsTextBox.Text);

    cnn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    //This is where the exception is thrown
    cnn.Close();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('Loan data INSERT success!');</script>");

}
```

The exception reads

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Arithmetic overflow error
> converting numeric to data type numeric. The statement has been
> terminated.'"

My Sql Loans table is coded as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Loans] (
[LoanNum]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CustName]     VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
[LoanAmount]   DECIMAL (9, 2) NOT NULL,
[AnualIntRate] DECIMAL (3, 3) NOT NULL,
[NumPayments]  INT            NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LoanNum] ASC));
```

I have tried multiple methods for using an `INSERT` SQL statement to send the the data to the database, but every method has given me problems. Even making a string where I concatenate the `TextBox.Text` for each piece of data from the form directly into the `INSERT` statement. I am trying to get this method working by tomorrow morning for a school project, and would much appreciate help. I intend on staying up until I can get it working.

Comment: What values are you trying to insert? And what are the datatypes in the database?

Comment: A name(string), a loan amount(a decimal), interest rate(decimal), and number of payments(int) it is the same in the database.

Comment: What are the actual values, and what is the scale and precision of your decimals?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the structure of your database table (column names, data types).  Also, can you actually do the insert (with the same values that you're trying to submit via the form) successfully through Management Studio?